# How to calculate Inverse FFT, when input sequence length isn't two the power N. I want to know algorithm/topic name. name

Tags: performance, matlab, fft

Basically FFT are working with input sequence of length 2<sup>n</sup>.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

But Matlab working fine whenever input sequences length not 2<sup>n</sup>. I hope that Matlab may be using Composite FFT.

Similarly IFFT are also working with input sequence of length 2<sup>n</sup>.

Anyone can let me know. what's the topic or algorithm name, which is using Matlab for IFFT. Just  like for FFT we can use Composite FFT.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking: how to compute the IFFT, or how the `ifft` function in MATLAB is implemented? In either case, there exist FFT algorithms that work with inputs or arbitrary size, there is nothing strange there.

Comment: The documentation on `fft` and `ifft` say "it's based on the FFTW library". Read the documentation of both the MATLAB functions, and check out http://fftw.org for implementations

Comment: @CrisLuengo Please can you tell me, what is algorithoms name for IFFT

Comment: The IFFT is implemented with the same algorithm as the FFT. See [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition): the equation for *Xk* as a function of *xn* is nearly identical to *xn* as a function of *Xk*, there is just a different sign in the exponent, and a different normalization constant.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab's FFT and IFFT implementations support input sequences of arbitrary length, including inputs whose lengths aren't a powers of 2.

Note however that while the performance remains O(N log(N)) for all lengths, it is generally significantly faster for lengths which can be factored into small primes (such as 2, 3, 5 & 7). For lengths which cannot be factored into small primes, a performance improvement can be obtained by zero padding the input sequence. For the forward FFT this consist of appending zeros to the end of the input sequence. For the inverse IFFT transform it is slightly more tricky since the zeros must be inserted in the middle of the sequence to keep the symmetry of the spectrum.